STM32L412 organization of option bytes and memory dump
I am trying to retrieve the firmware from an STM32L412 using an ST-LINK/V2-1 debugger-programmer. According to the datasheet, the option bytes are located at address 0x1FFF7800, but I can't find the layout for this part of memory to decode the access permissions.
Here, I found the layout for a similar microcontroller, but I don't think it applies to the STM32L412 since it doesn't match the memory map provided in the datasheet.
The datasheet also mentions Proprietary Code Readout Protection (PCROP), but I don't understand where it is located or how the address space to protect is specified.
Assuming the RDP is set to protection level 1 and PCROP_RDP is enabled, there is no way to dump the uploaded firmware, correct?
